# bodyparser changing the float number(0.0) to integer(0)? whats the solution?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

X server hitting the post req to Y server. x server body data {"number":0.0}, but when receiving it in y server (nodejs) its changing to {"number":0} in the req.body tag. every req through bodyParser.json()

why it is changing? it should get what the x server posted right? help me out.

tried with bodyParser.raw(), bodyParser.text() dosnt provide the body tag.

Comment: If you must have it in that format, use a string. Otherwise, isn't `0 === 0.0`?

Comment: Javascript has single data type for floats and integers `number` (well, at least at the moment `BigInt` is still staging). So `0 === 0.0`

Comment: its 3rd party request we can't change it to string. and i am creating hmac (sha256) using the body. so one dot changes the complete hmac string.

Comment: There might be more problems than that. The order of keys is not guaranteed so you need to use raw request body to calculate checksums.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate a HMAC over the raw request body, you shouldn't be parsing it, or at least *first* take the raw request body, calculate the HMAC, *then* parse it.

To do the latter, you can use [`express.json`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)'s `verify` option:

```
app.use(express.json({
  verify(req, res, buf, encoding) {
    req._hmac = hmac(buf);
  }
}));
```

This will use a function called `hmac` to calculate a HMAC over the request body (passed as a Buffer in the `buf` argument). It will then continue to parse the request body as JSON.

Caveats:

- it will calculate the HMAC for every request that passed a request body;
- it won't work if calculating the HMAC is asynchronous.

Both issues are relatively easy to solve, though.

Comment: Thanks mate! its worked out. As you said two issues, need a workaround. let me take care.

Answer (score 0):

Since I faced the same problem, I resolved using bodyparser in this way:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({
   type: 'application/json'
}))
```

In this way the request with application/json header are considered as text, and in req.body you will have the string representation of the json.